# Scala: Zip two lists into json array format

Tags: arrays, json, scala, list, maps

I have two lists that look like this:

```
List("key1", "key2")
List("val1", "val2")
```

I'm trying to get it into this JSON-like format:

```
[{"key1":"val1"},{"key2","val2"}]
```

Right now, this is what I'm using:

```
val output = List(attrKeys.zip(attrValues).toMap)
```

But it gives me this:

```
[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]
```

How do I get this into a list of separate map objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attrKeys.zip(attrValues).map(Map(_))
```